# I don't know why my video does not play on the html file and how I can insert multimedia file on an html file>

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <video width="400" height="400" controls>
    <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/ogg" />
    Your browser does not support video tag
    </video>
</body>
```

to wrap it up:
I was trying to solve this problem in the last few days, so I give some additional information:

1. I know mp4 is supported by Chrome
   2.my video file is stored in the same folder as the html file( with the same directory)
   3.some other programmers suggested using iframe so don't recommend this
2. the same problem goes for my audio files
3. when I write a http source instead, it does not open again.
4. I also tried writing in the code controls="controls" too.
5. I know I left the title part, my focus is on the body
   I wonder what the problem is. I really appreciate if you help me to figure that out.
   thank you in advance.

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<source>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-source-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: @Hanieh Can't reproduce the problem ( https://jsfiddle.net/ou4p6fk7/ ). Make sure that your video URL is correct and really exists. For example create a link to video directly (`<a href="movie.mp4">link</a>`) with the same value to see that it is able to open.

Comment: @vee The point is that doing so it pointless as this is not XHTML, the slash has no meaning in HTML, it does nothing and browsers are instructed to ignore it.

Comment: Hello! when I delete slashes, vscode give me error and mark the tages red. by the way I tried this way, it did not work.

Comment: tnx vee. my question is why when I link it to a mp4 file to my c drive with same folder as the html file, it does not open? and my another question is when I want to receive a video link address I just right click to copy link address and it so unorderly and long that it does not work but the example you commented had a sound http address, how can search for a correct http address and why cannot I refer to somewhere stored in my system?

Comment: isn't it because I add DOCTYPE html tag to the beginning of my html file?

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome disables auto-play audio, so it can't auto-play video. To give autoplay, add a "muted" attribute.

```
<video controls autoplay muted>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am new to stack over flow, and I don't know how to post pictures, can ya help me.

Comment: "Ask Question"---->"Body"---->image button---->"paste"---->"Paste image or link:"---->Copy your image into the input box

Answer (score -1):

I Found the answer to this question, in case you want to insert images, videos or audios you should take care of the directory your files are saved in, if they are in the same, which should preferably be, use this: ./image.png

Comment: This is a great comment, but not enough information or detail to warrant answering